# i am trying to fecth html page with react-native-html-parser

Tags: react-native

How to parse html page from fetch response?
I have checked both async and regular promise syntax but nothing seems to compile:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');  var DOMParser = require('react-native-html-parser').DOMParser;






function getbooks() {

  fetch('https://github.github.io/fetch/').then(function(response) {
if (response) {
  return response
} else {
  var error = new Error(response.statusText)
  error.response = response
  throw error
}
})
}
const books=getbooks();
console.log(books);


var DOMParser = require('react-native-html-parser').DOMParser;
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
    books);

console.log(doc);
console.log('end');
```

Answer (score 0):

What gets returned from your endpoint?

You Can try:
**NOTE: Your trying to log a response from something that is asyncrhonus. You need to use**

> async and await (with promises). Something like...

```
async function getBooks(){
var response = await fetch('https://github.github.io/fetch/', {
method: 'GET',
headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
},
}).then((response) => {console.log(response);return response})
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        return {error: "Couldn't get books"}
    });
console.log(response);

}

getBooks();
```

Comment: i have got body of http response: 'undefined
[xmldom error] invalid document source 
@#[line:0,col:undefined]
undefined
end
Body {
  url: 'https://github.github.io/fetch/',
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: 
   Headers {
     _headers: 
      { server: [Array],
'

Comment: undefined [xmldom] - response is not applying as html to native-react component for parsing html dom. Would you suggest alternative?

Comment: I also realize your function is asynchronus, and therefor it will always return undefined below. You need to make this asyncrhonus and use you 'await' and 'async'.

Comment: Check out my most recent edit, you can log the response there. If you need the response, try using a promise to return the value to your function and then handle it.

Comment: I have tryied to make it asynchronus and i got what i am asking in response - html headers but not html contents to pass them further to component. Seemslike i need somethinglike body-parser but for react-native.